# How to access a variable defined in designer code from other classes?

Tags: c#, global-variables, global

I'm trying to make a game that is round-based, and I want to make it so that the user is able to define the amount of rounds from the beginning. I've made it so that the user will input a number into a text box, and then a button will put that number into a variable called length by using "length = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)". Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to access this length variable from the Form1 class so that I can set the number of rounds. Can someone please point me in the right direction? I've tried doing SpeedDialog.length (SpeedDialog is a windows form designer class that I'm getting the info from), but it did not seem to work, saying that I cannot reference a non-static class. Could I fix this problem by making SpeedDialog static (I'm thinking not but I could be wrong)? Thank you so much! I really appreciate it!

Here's my Form1 class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace BrickO1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const int kNumberOfTries = 3;

    public int rounds;
    private Ball TheBall = new Ball();
    private Paddle ThePaddle = new Paddle();
    private Paddle TheOtherPaddle = new Paddle();

    //   private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;

    private Score TheScore = null;
    private Score TheOtherScore = null;
    private Thread oThread = null; //thread is used to run sounds independently

    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    public static extern long PlaySound(String lpszName, long hModule, long dwFlags);
    //method PlaySound must be imported from the .dll file winmm



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ThePaddle.Position.X = 5;
        ThePaddle.Position.Y = this.ClientRectangle.Bottom - ThePaddle.Height;

        TheOtherPaddle.Position.X = 5;
        TheOtherPaddle.Position.Y = 0;
        // this.ClientRectangle refers to the current container (the instance of Form1)

        TheBall.Position.Y = this.ClientRectangle.Bottom - 200;

        TheScore = new Score(ClientRectangle.Right - 30, ClientRectangle.Bottom - 40);
        TheOtherScore = new Score(ClientRectangle.Right - 30, ClientRectangle.Bottom - 370);
        //positions the score - 0 at this moment

        // choose Level
        SpeedDialog dlg = new SpeedDialog();
       /* makes sure that, if the DialogResult property of the button "OK" is on, 
        the SpeedDialog form appears and stays on the screen, and timer's Interval
        gets an appropriate value */
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)                                               
        {
            timer1.Interval = dlg.Speed;
        }

    }
         private string m_strCurrentSoundFile = "BallOut.wav"; //sound file is initialized

    public void PlayASound() //method to play a sound; to be called by a thread
     {
        if (m_strCurrentSoundFile.Length > 0)
        {
            PlaySound(Application.StartupPath + "\\" + m_strCurrentSoundFile, 0, 0); 
            /* the above gives full path to the location of the sound file from the startup path
               of the executable file: Application.StartupPath */
        }
        m_strCurrentSoundFile = "";
        oThread.Abort(); //aborts the tread playing sound
    }

    public void PlaySoundInThread(string wavefile) //creates and starts a new thread to play a sound
    {
        m_strCurrentSoundFile = wavefile;
        oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(PlayASound)); //calls the method PlayASound
        oThread.Start();
    }


    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e) //method to draw Form1
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height);
        TheScore.Draw(g);
        TheOtherScore.Draw(g);
        ThePaddle.Draw(g);
        TheOtherPaddle.Draw(g);
        TheBall.Draw(g);
    }
    private void CheckForCollision()
    {
        if (TheBall.Position.X < 0)  // hit the left side, switch polarity
        {
            TheBall.XStep *= -1;
            TheBall.Position.X += TheBall.XStep;
            PlaySoundInThread("WallHit.wav");
        }

        if (TheBall.Position.Y < 0)  // hit the top of the form
        {
            //Lost the ball for 2nd paddle
            TheScore.Increment();
            if(TheScore.Count == SpeedDialog.length)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Congrats! Player 1 wins!");
                Application.Exit();
            }
            Reset();
            PlaySoundInThread("BallOut.wav");
        }


        if (TheBall.Position.X > this.ClientRectangle.Right - TheBall.Width)  // hit the right side, switch polarity
        {
            TheBall.XStep *= -1;
            TheBall.Position.X += TheBall.XStep;
            PlaySoundInThread("WallHit.wav");
        }

        if (TheBall.Position.Y > this.ClientRectangle.Bottom - TheBall.YStep) // lost the ball!
        {
            TheOtherScore.Increment();
            if (TheScore.Count == SpeedDialog.length)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Congrats! Player 2 wins!");
                Application.Exit();
            }
            Reset();
            PlaySoundInThread("BallOut.wav");
        }

        int hp = HitsPaddle(TheBall.Position); //check if the ball hit the paddle
        if (hp > -1)// checks if the ball is not lost
        {
            PlaySoundInThread("PaddleHit.wav");
            switch (hp) //new direction of the ball depends on which quarter of the paddle is hit
            {
                case 1:
                    TheBall.XStep = -7;
                    TheBall.YStep = -3;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    TheBall.XStep = -5;
                    TheBall.YStep = -5;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    TheBall.XStep = 5;
                    TheBall.YStep = -5;
                    break;
                default:
                    TheBall.XStep = 7;
                    TheBall.YStep = -3;
                    break;

            }
        }

        int hp2 = HitsPaddle2(TheBall.Position); //check if the ball hit the paddle
        if (hp2 > -1)// checks if the ball is not lost
        {
            PlaySoundInThread("PaddleHit.wav");
            switch (hp2) //new direction of the ball depends on which quarter of the paddle is hit
            {
                case 1:
                    TheBall.XStep = -7;
                    TheBall.YStep = 3;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    TheBall.XStep = -5;
                    TheBall.YStep = 5;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    TheBall.XStep = 5;
                    TheBall.YStep = 5;
                    break;
                default:
                    TheBall.XStep = 7;
                    TheBall.YStep = 3;
                    break;

            }
        }
    }


    private int HitsPaddle(Point p)
    {
        Rectangle PaddleRect = ThePaddle.GetBounds(); //current position of the paddle

        if (p.Y >= this.ClientRectangle.Bottom - (PaddleRect.Height + TheBall.Height))//If the ball has hit the paddle according to its y value
        {
            if ((p.X > PaddleRect.Left) && (p.X < PaddleRect.Right)) //ball hits the paddle (horizontally)!
            {
                if ((p.X > PaddleRect.Left) && (p.X <= PaddleRect.Left + PaddleRect.Width / 4))
                    return 1; //hits leftmost quarter of the paddle
                else if ((p.X > PaddleRect.Left + PaddleRect.Width / 4) && (p.X <= PaddleRect.Left + PaddleRect.Width / 2))
                    return 2; //hits the second quarter of the paddle
                else if ((p.X > PaddleRect.Left + PaddleRect.Width / 2) && (p.X <= PaddleRect.Right - PaddleRect.Width / 2))
                    return 3; //hits the third quarter of the paddle
                else
                    return 4; //hits the rightmost quarter of the paddle
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private int HitsPaddle2(Point q)
    {
        Rectangle Paddle2Rect = TheOtherPaddle.GetBounds(); //current position of the paddle

        if (q.Y <= this.ClientRectangle.Top + Paddle2Rect.Height)
        {
            if ((q.X > Paddle2Rect.Left) && (q.X < Paddle2Rect.Right)) //ball hits the paddle!
            {
                if ((q.X > Paddle2Rect.Left) && (q.X <= Paddle2Rect.Left + Paddle2Rect.Width / 4))
                    return 1; //hits leftmost quarter of the paddle
                else if ((q.X > Paddle2Rect.Left + Paddle2Rect.Width / 4) && (q.X <= Paddle2Rect.Left + Paddle2Rect.Width / 2))
                    return 2; //hits the second quarter of the paddle
                else if ((q.X > Paddle2Rect.Left + Paddle2Rect.Width / 2) && (q.X <= Paddle2Rect.Right - Paddle2Rect.Width / 2))
                    return 3; //hits the third quarter of the paddle
                else
                    return 4; //hits the rightmost quarter of the paddle
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private void Reset() //resets the ball, stops timer, and redraws the main form
    {
        TheBall.XStep = 5;
        TheBall.YStep = 5;
        TheBall.Position.Y = this.ClientRectangle.Bottom - 190;
        TheBall.Position.X = 5;
        timer1.Stop();
        TheBall.UpdateBounds();
        Invalidate(TheBall.GetBounds());
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e) //runs one round of the game, when started
    {
        TheBall.UpdateBounds(); //gets the ball position
        Invalidate(TheBall.GetBounds()); //redraws the ball
        TheBall.Move(); //moves the ball 
        TheBall.UpdateBounds(); //updates position of the ball
        Invalidate(TheBall.GetBounds()); //redraws the boll
        CheckForCollision(); //checks for collision
        Invalidate(TheScore.GetFrame()); //redraws the score
        Invalidate(TheOtherScore.GetFrame());
    }
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string result = e.KeyData.ToString();
        Invalidate(ThePaddle.GetBounds());
        switch (result)
        {
            case "Left":
                ThePaddle.MoveLeft();
                Invalidate(ThePaddle.GetBounds());
                if (timer1.Enabled == false) //starts the game if it does not run yet
                    timer1.Start();
                break;
            case "Right":
                ThePaddle.MoveRight(ClientRectangle.Right);
                Invalidate(ThePaddle.GetBounds());
                if (timer1.Enabled == false) //starts the game if it does not run yet
                    timer1.Start();
                break;
            case "Z":
                TheOtherPaddle.MoveLeft();
                Invalidate(TheOtherPaddle.GetBounds());
                if (timer1.Enabled == false) //starts the game if it does not run yet
                    timer1.Start();
                break;
            case "C":
                TheOtherPaddle.MoveRight(ClientRectangle.Right);
                Invalidate(TheOtherPaddle.GetBounds());
                if (timer1.Enabled == false) //starts the game if it does not run yet
                    timer1.Start();
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }

    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
 }
 }
```

And here's the SpeedDialog class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BrickO1
{
public partial class SpeedDialog : Form

{
    public int Speed = 250;
    private static int length = 0;

    public SpeedDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SlowRadio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SlowRadio.Checked)
            Speed = 100;
        else if (MediumRadio.Checked)
            Speed = 100;
        else
            Speed = 50;

        length = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        if(length == 0)
        {
           length = 5;
        }
    }
   public int SelectedLength { get{ return length; }} 

    private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void SpeedDialog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void groupBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void maskedTextBox1_MaskInputRejected(object sender, MaskInputRejectedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }


}
}
```

Thanks again!!!

Comment: at the least non-standard way, make your variable static

Comment: expose it as a property.  A form is just a class like any other

Comment: @techspider So I made the variable static, but the number that I input in my text box doesn't have any effect, and I'm pretty sure the program would run infinitely if I let it.